# webform alter drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

i'm new on drupal 8 and i want to try to custom the basic template of the webform module with my own template in TWIG , SASS.
I know i have to create a custom module but after read the drupal documentation , i don't know how i can do it correctly.
Any one can help me ?
i try to create a module with this code

```
function webform_example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $id) {
  if ($id == 'webform_submission_contact_form') {
    $form['elements']['name']['#title'] = t('Name');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code example makes perfect sense to me.

You can also use [hook_form_BASE_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8.5.x), which for the Contact form would be webform_example_form_webform_submission_contact_form_alter().

Comment: thank a lot for your answer but how i can create this custom module to use this function

Comment: Not detailing what your module/theme name is and what the base id is makes your answer pretty much useless.